# Need help Ordering qcut categorical outputs on x axis in matplotlib Barplot in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've carved up List Price Values from my dataset into quantiles and created a new column with the quantile buckets:

```
JNF_prices_pb['List Price Bins'] = pd.qcut(JNF_prices_pb['List Price Value'], 
labels = ['0 - 7.99', '8 - 8.99', '9 - 9.99', '10 - 10.99', '11 - 12.99', '13 - 14.99', '15 - 16.99', '17+'], 
q = 8, precision = 0)
```

I'm looking to plot the normalized value counts of products in each pricing bucket, but when I plot these in matplotlib, I'm having a lot of trouble reordering the xticks such that they are in the order of the labels in the code above.

Here's my plot code:

```
plt.figure(figsize = (8,5))
JNF_prices_pb['List Price Bins'].value_counts(normalize = True).plot(kind = 'bar')
plt.xticks(rotation = 45, fontsize = 14)
plt.yticks(fontsize = 14)
plt.ylabel('% of Total', fontsize = 14)
plt.xlabel('List Price ($)', fontsize = 14)
plt.title('Juvenile Nonfiction -- General -- Paperback', fontsize = 16, fontweight = 'bold');
```

I've attempted to set the 'ticks' and 'labels' in the plt.xticks(), but I keep getting getting an error:

```
ConversionError: Failed to convert value(s) to axis units: ['0 -
7.99', '8 - 8.99', '9 - 9.99', '10 - 10.99', '11 - 12.99', '13 - 14.99', '15 - 16.99', '17+']
```

Comment: Did you try `...value_counts(normalize=True, sort=False)` to prevent sorting the values?

Comment: Why do you think `pd.qcut()` would create bins such as `'0-7.99'` instead of some more arbitrary ranges?